# Salen todos los tooltips a la vez, amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Tengo esta gráfica creada con amcharts4, el problema es que estoy intentando que los tooltips se vean uno por uno. Es decir, si yo pongo el ratón encima de una barra me muestra todos los tooltips y yo quiero que se muestre el correspondiente al que le he puesto el ratón encima solo, no todos a la vez. Los tooltips se muestran bien, pero tapo los nombres por temas de privacidad. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                        loaderContainer2.style.display = "block";

                    var chartContainer =
                        document.getElementById("chartdiv");

                    var chart = am4core.create(
                        chartContainer,
                        am4charts.XYChart
                    );

                    chart.colors.step = 2;
                    chart.padding(30, 30, 10, 30);

                    chart.data = data.lst_graficas_consumo.flatMap(
                        (item) =>
                            item.puntos.map((punto) => ({
                                Xvalue: punto.Xvalue,
                                Yvalue1: punto.Yvalue1,
                            }))
                    );

                    chart.svgContainer.measure();

                    chart.data.forEach(function (item) {
                        item.Xvalue = new Date(item.Xvalue * 1000); 
                    });

                
                    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
                        new am4charts.DateAxis()
                    );
                    dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 40;
                    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5; 
                    dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("day", "MMM dd");
                    dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey(
                        "day",
                        "MMM dd"
                    );
                    dateAxis.tooltipDateFormat = "dd/MM";
                    dateAxis.zoomable = true; 

                    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
                        new am4charts.ValueAxis()
                    );
                    valueAxis.min = 0;

                    var toggleButton =
                        document.getElementById("toggleButton");
                    var legendDiv =
                        document.getElementById("legenddiv");

                    toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        if (legendDiv.style.display === "none") {
                            legendDiv.style.display = "block";
                        } else {
                            legendDiv.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    });

                    var colors = [
                        "#63b598",
                        "#ce7d78",
                        ...
                      
                    ];

                    // Crear la leyenda
                    chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();


                    chart.legend.align = "center"; 
                    chart.legend.fontSize = 15; 
                    chart.legend.marginTop = 10;

                    var legendContainer = am4core.create(
                        "legenddiv",
                        am4core.Container
                    );
                    legendContainer.width = am4core.percent(100);
                    legendContainer.height = am4core.percent(100);
                    chart.legend.parent = legendContainer;

                    data.lst_graficas_consumo.forEach(function (serieData, index) {
                        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
                    
                        // Configurar los datos de la serie
                        series.dataFields.valueY = "Yvalue1";
                        series.dataFields.dateX = "Xvalue";
                        series.clustered = true; 
                    
                        // Configurar la anchura de las columnas
                        series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100); 
                    
                        series.columns.template.fill = am4core.color(
                            colors[index % colors.length]
                        );
                        series.columns.template.stroke = am4core.color(
                            colors[index % colors.length]
                        );
                    
                        series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
                    
                        series.data = serieData.puntos.map(function (punto) {
                            return {
                                Xvalue: new Date(punto.Xvalue),
                                Yvalue1: punto.Yvalue1,
                            };
                        });
                    
                        // Configurar el tooltip de la serie
                        series.columns.template.tooltipText =
                            "[bold]{name}: {valueY}[/] {uds}"; 
                        series.tooltip.pointerBehavior = "sticky"; 
                        series.tooltip.pointerBehaviorAuto = false; 
                        series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = true; 
                    
                        // Configurar la función de desactivación del tooltip
                        series.columns.template.events.on("out", function (event) {
                            event.target.isHover = false;
                        });
                    
                        // Configurar la función de activación del tooltip
                        series.columns.template.events.on("over", function (event) {
                            event.target.isHover = true;
                        });

                    
                        // Configurar los datos de la serie con el arreglo de puntos
                        series.data = serieData.puntos.map(function (punto) {
                            return {
                                Xvalue: new Date(punto.Xvalue),
                                Yvalue1: punto.Yvalue1,
                                name: serieData.nombre, // Agregar el nombre de la serie
                                uds: serieData.uds // Agregar las unidades de la serie
                            };
                        });
                    

                        data.lst_graficas_consumo.forEach(
                            (grafica, index) => {
                                const nombre = grafica.nombre;
                                const series =
                                    chart.series.getIndex(index); 
                                const uds = grafica.uds;

                                if (series) {
                                    series.columns.template.tooltipText =
                                        "[bold]" +
                                        nombre +
                                        ": {valueY}[/]" +
                                        uds;
                                    series.name = nombre;
                                }
                            }
                        );

                        series.columns.template.tooltipY = 0; 

                        // Configurar el formato de fecha para el eje X
                        series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

                        // Configurar los datos de la serie 
                        series.data = serieData.puntos.map(function (
                            punto
                        ) {
                            return {
                                Xvalue: new Date(punto.Xvalue),
                                Yvalue1: punto.Yvalue1,
                            };
                        });

                        // Configurar la anchura de las columnas
                        series.columns.template.width =
                            am4core.percent(100); // Ajusta el valor según sea necesario

                        series.columns.template.fill = am4core.color(
                            colors[index % colors.length]
                        );
                        series.columns.template.stroke = am4core.color(
                            colors[index % colors.length]
                        );
                    });

                    // Configurar cursor
                    chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
                    chart.cursor.lineX.strokeOpacity = 0;
                    chart.cursor.lineY.strokeOpacity = 0;

                    // Habilitar zoom
                    chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

                    // Agregar animación de aparición de las columnas
                    chart.events.on("ready", function () {
                        chartdiv.classList.remove("hidden");
                        chartdiv.classList.add("visible");
                    });
                    chart.events.on("ready", function () {
                        loaderContainer2.style.display = "none";
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se muestran todos los Tooltips, ya que estás definiendo un solo cursor para todo el gráfico, debes definir un cursor por cada serie.

Primeramente, dentro de la iteración define el objeto `XYCursor` y después de crear el cursor se asignará a cada serie. Elimina la definición del cursor que se encuentra fuera de la iteración.

```
                    ...
                    ...

                    data.lst_graficas_consumo.forEach(function (serieData, index) {

                        //* Define cursor ahora por cada serie.
            var cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
                        cursor.lineX.strokeOpacity = 0;
                        cursor.lineY.strokeOpacity = 0;
                        chart.cursorContainer.addChild(cursor);


                        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
                    
                        //Configurar los datos de la serie
                        series.dataFields.valueY = "Yvalue1";
                        series.dataFields.dateX = "Xvalue";
                        series.clustered = true; 
                    
                        // Configurar la anchura de las columnas
                        series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100); 
                    
                        series.columns.template.fill = am4core.color(
                            colors[index % colors.length]
                        );
                        series.columns.template.stroke = am4core.color(
                            colors[index % colors.length]
                        );
                    
                        series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
                    
                        series.data = serieData.puntos.map(function (punto) {
                            return {
                                Xvalue: new Date(punto.Xvalue),
                                Yvalue1: punto.Yvalue1,
                            };
                        });
                    
                        // Configurar el tooltip de la serie
                        series.columns.template.tooltipText =
                            "[bold]{name}: {valueY}[/] {uds}"; 
                        series.tooltip.pointerBehavior = "sticky"; 
                        series.tooltip.pointerBehaviorAuto = false; 
                        series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = true; 
                    
                        // Configurar la función de desactivación del tooltip
                        series.columns.template.events.on("out", function (event) {
                            event.target.isHover = false;
                        });
                    
                        // Configurar la función de activación del tooltip
                        series.columns.template.events.on("over", function (event) {
                            event.target.isHover = true;
                        });

                    
                        // Configurar los datos de la serie con el arreglo de puntos
                        series.data = serieData.puntos.map(function (punto) {
                            return {
                                Xvalue: new Date(punto.Xvalue),
                                Yvalue1: punto.Yvalue1,
                                name: serieData.nombre, // Agregar el nombre de la serie
                                uds: serieData.uds // Agregar las unidades de la serie
                            };
                        });
                    

                        data.lst_graficas_consumo.forEach(
                            (grafica, index) => {
                                const nombre = grafica.nombre;
                                const series =
                                    chart.series.getIndex(index); 
                                const uds = grafica.uds;

                                if (series) {
                                    series.columns.template.tooltipText =
                                        "[bold]" +
                                        nombre +
                                        ": {valueY}[/]" +
                                        uds;
                                    series.name = nombre;
                                }
                            }
                        );

                        series.columns.template.tooltipY = 0; 

                        // Configurar el formato de fecha para el eje X
                        series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

                        // Configurar los datos de la serie 
                        series.data = serieData.puntos.map(function (
                            punto
                        ) {
                            return {
                                Xvalue: new Date(punto.Xvalue),
                                Yvalue1: punto.Yvalue1,
                            };
                        });

                        // Configurar la anchura de las columnas
                        series.columns.template.width =
                            am4core.percent(100); // Ajusta el valor según sea necesario

                        series.columns.template.fill = am4core.color(
                            colors[index % colors.length]
                        );
                        series.columns.template.stroke = am4core.color(
                            colors[index % colors.length]
                        );


                        //* Define cursor para serie actual
                        cursor.series = series;


                    });

                    // Configurar cursor
                    //*Debes definir un cursor por cada serie, no para el gráfico.
                    /*chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
                    chart.cursor.lineX.strokeOpacity = 0;
                    chart.cursor.lineY.strokeOpacity = 0;*/

                    ...
                    ...
```